# maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object when creating child page of parent page

Tags: python, django

This is my child code page

```
{% if post.page_set.all %}
 {% for child in post.page_set.all %}
   <div>
     <h5>
      <a href="" style="margin-left:10px;">{{child.title}}</a>&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'add_child_page' pk=child.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-plus"  style="font-size:15px ;color:#2F4F4F;"></i></a>
     </h5>
     {% include "makerobosapp/child_code.html" with post=post %}
   </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And this is my homepage where i want to show child post title

{% block content %}

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="post-content">
  <h3>
    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a>&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'add_child_page' pk=post.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size:20px ;color:#2F4F4F;"></i></a>
  </h3>
  <p>{{post.content| safe |linebreaksbr}}</p>
  <div class="date">
    <p>published date: {{ post.published_date }}</p>
  </div>
   {% include "makerobosapp/child_code.html" with post=post %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you wanted to recurse into the child, not the parent:

```
{% include "makerobosapp/child_code.html" with post=child %}
```